# How to reload the listView on click of a button in android?

Tags: android

I have created a view in which i have 1 list view and 2 buttons. The first button is for deleting the selected list view and the 2nd button is for deleting the deleted the entire data from the table. I want that if I delete the entire data from the table the list view should get refreshed an it should get reloaded. Please help me out in achieving this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use should use notifyDataSetChanged () method to refresh your listview...

Call notifyDataSetChanged() on your Adapter

see this link........
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29

Comment: hi Sujit! I am very new to android.Please give me some code examples if u can.

Comment: the event in which you want to refresh the ListView just call the notifyDataSetChanged () methods of your adapter that you are passing to your ListView.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the following way

1) create a handler to add or remove item to your listview

```
static final int UPDATE_LIST =1;
static final int CLEAR_LIST = 2;

    private Handler photoGridHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case UPDATE_LIST:

                int index = msg.arg1;

                Bitmap bitMapImage = (Bitmap) msg.obj;
                mylist.add(bitMapImage);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;

            case CLEAR_LIST:
                                 int index = msg.arg1;
                mylist.remove(index );
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
break;

            }
        };
    };
```

2) call this handler for different type of operation either you want to add data or remove data from the list. So handler should be called inside your `onClickListener()`. See the below how to call handler

```
        to remove element from the list use the following

Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = CLEAR_LIST;
        msg.arg1 = index;

        photoGridHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

to add elements to the list use the folowing

```
Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = UPDATE_LIST;
        msg.arg1 = index;
        msg.obj = image;
        photoGridHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Thanks
Deepak